# Winui 3 how to make a new app window at button click

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, winui-3

Am building an app with Winui 3 so XAML and C#

Ok, how to make a new instance of the app at runtime. So in one of the pages I have a button with content "Open new window". At button click I want to open a new self/ window from the app I am building. In the winui 3 sample app there is an example, but that doesn't work for people who uses the newest version of winui 3 and have the app created from the app designer.
Also when looking around for Microsoft documentation didn't get me where I want to be.

Have searched the internet found the following examples that didn't work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window
https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/Navigation/NavigationRootPage.xaml.cs

What I got was breakdown after breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky but give it a try.

1. Create a dummy file with a unique extension in the *Assets* folder and make sure to set its **Build Action** property as **Content**. In this case, my dummy file is a text file named "dummy.test".
2. Go to **Package.appxmanifest**, **Declarations** and add a **File Type Associations** declaration and set these properties:

   - Display name: Test
   - Name: test
   - File type: .test
3. In your button click event handler, launch the file. This should launch the app associated with the "test" extension, which is your app in this case.

```cs
private async void LaunchAppButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\dummy.test");
    _ = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to do the same thing that the **WinUI 3 Gallery** app does, you can get all the code from the repo.

Here's some part of it:

- [WindowHelper.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/Helper/WindowHelper.cs#L28)

  The `CreateWindow()` method essentially just creates a `Window`, adds it to a collection just to keep track of it and returns it.
- [ThemeHelper.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/Helper/ThemeHelper.cs)
- [NavigationRootPage](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/Navigation/NavigationRootPage.xaml)

So, basically you just need to create a `Window`, set your main content and activate it.

```cs
Window newWindow = new();
newWindow.Content = /* your main content*/
newWindow.Activate();
```

Comment: No that is not what I want. What i want is that I get a "copy" of the app, or to say that the app opens itself in a new window, I think you haven't checked the links in my question

Comment: You definitely mean [Rich activation with the app lifecycle API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/applifecycle/applifecycle-rich-activation#activation-details-for-unpackaged-apps).

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: this is what they have done in the winui 3 template app: `// C# code to create a new window
var newWindow = WindowHelper.CreateWindow();
var rootPage = new NavigationRootPage();
rootPage.RequestedTheme = ThemeHelper.RootTheme;
newWindow.Content = rootPage;
newWindow.Activate();

// C# code to navigate in the new window
var targetPageType = typeof(NewControlsPage);
string targetPageArguments = string.Empty;
rootPage.Navigate(targetPageType, targetPageArguments);` but that is not working because the use other helpers and navigationlogic

Comment: That is basically my first answer. You can see the code in the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/CreateMultipleWindowsPage.xaml.cs#L33).

Comment: Yes but you can't read? I said, that is not working becauses they use other helpers, relationships and structures, and that's also why Winui 3 sucks. Their is not one single clear explanation or documentation about the more difficult items!

Comment: In this case, it's not that complicated. All you need is in the WinUI 3 code. I updated my answer with more details. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: No you can't read, can you? !!! **That is not working, because they use other structures and things, which is not by default in your (designer followed) app project!**

Comment: Weird. Both my answers are based on plain projects that I actually implemented for this answer, and I made sure they work (creates a new window) at least on my side. I'm afraid I can't help much with this one. Good luck.

Comment: The purpose is not to make a new window, because I know how that works, the problem is (read my question thoroughly) that it is not possible for me to clone the app on runtime, so clicking a button makes a new instance/ copy/ new screen from the app. I don't know how to call that but it is like chrome making a new window. The content is already in, I want the same but than for my app

Comment: I guess you mean you want to run a new app with the same contents (or status). I have never done this but AFAIK, you can't just clone an app like this. You might need to pass some kind of data to the new app so it can construct itself to have the same contents. This could be done by creating a temp file with my first answer.

Comment: I also think that the link @YangXiaoPo-MSFT posted might help. You'll need to construct the app when it's activated.

Comment: @jan-peterPoppe Did you mean the *Move tab to new window* function in chrome?
That's just [Show multiple views with AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window) or try [TabView](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/9b0d8f6fa5062450163cd90277cc212e96064a86/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TabViewPage.xaml#L346)?

Comment: yes, but instead of only one tab, the user gets on button click [the same app but again] like the wine 3 sample app, **please have a look there how it works!'go to the last navigation menu item about windowing a look for multiple windows!** Here is the code behind that page: https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/CreateMultipleWindowsPage.xaml.cs have a look there! **The problem for me is that those properties and functions do not exist even though I have created my app with the winui 3 designer guidance.  The multiple views link codes didn't work for me

Comment: The code is just the same as [what @AndrewKeepCoding answered](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/4413936468fc89143f40e171f65085bda28aacd2/Samples/Windowing/cs-winui/ZOrderPage.xaml.cs#L67). Or you simply create [another main window](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/4413936468fc89143f40e171f65085bda28aacd2/Samples/Windowing/cs-winui/App.xaml.cs#L19) like `Window mainWindow2 = new MainWindow();`.

Comment: Can you all read **this is not working for me and want not a blank window but have a look at the sample app and look what it does** Reply me when you have done it!!!!!!!!